# Airport Extreme Internet Dropping

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, connection, airport-extreme

I am using an Airport Extreme router in my house, and up until recently, it used to work great. However, as of late, my wireless internet connection has started dropping, and I was wondering if you all could help me pinpoint the cause. Here are some details:

1. The WiFi only drops on two Windows laptops using the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 wireless card. One is running Windows 7, the other Windows 8.1. Both wireless card drivers are at their respective latest updates.
2. Every time the wireless drops, it results in a DNS error on Chrome. I have tried both OpenDNS and Google DNS, but the same result occurs.
3. Interestingly enough, one day my wireless dropped, as I couldn't access any web page in Chrome, and my SSH session ended. However, my torrent download continued to run.

If you need any other details, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Which exact model of AirPort Extreme? What firmware version is it running? Is it doing NAT? Is there another box on your network doing NAT as well? When the "drop" happens, does it happen to both laptops at the same time? Are you saying that when the laptops experience the drop, other devices can still use the Internet just fine? When the drop happens, can you still ping public servers *by IP address* (not by name)?

Comment: 5th generation.

Whatever the latest version is (can't check exact version right now, sorry!)

I don't think it's doing NAT. Maybe it is? What is that, or how would I tell? What does this affect?

Yes, I'm pretty sure it happens at the same time, maybe a little bit of delay in between.

Yes, my phone and tablet can access the wireless, and the wired computer continues to work.

Haven't tried pinging IP's. If I could do this, what would it imply?

Comment: Have you configured DNS in router? What about windows firewall?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using both OpenDNS and Google DNS servers. Maybe I'll try my ISP's servers, but they're pretty slow. As for Windows firewall, it's on on both computers. Is there anything router related that needs to be done?